# SSRS: Set diff background colors to entire row in Pivot Matrix based on field value , including empty/null cells in that row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

** Using SSRS 2008 R2

I came across an issue, when trying to highlight (set background color) an entire row in a Pivot Matrix - it's only changing the backgroundcolor for the cells in the row that have values.  the others are staying white.  I'm looking to set the background color for the entire row, even those empty cells.

In the editor, I've highlighted the row, and in the "BackgroundColor" property put a switch statement in for the expression.

=Switch(Fields!Department.Value="Accounting", "Yellow", Fields!Department.Value="HR", "Blue",Fields!Department.Value="Marketing", "Red")

```
Department     JAN      FEB     MAR     APR     MAY
-----------------------------------------------------------
John                     3                       2
Mark            1        4               1
Tim                              2
```

So in the example above, this works only for the Employee Name cell, and the cells with number values, the rest (empty cells) have no background color.

Any help in how to get the entire row, IE for John (in Accounting) how to get JAN, MAR, APR to be yellow as well?

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!!

Comment: each text box needs to be set separately using teh same express

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking on the row header and setting the color from there or are you just selecting all of the textboxes individually?

Comment: @PeterHe All of the cells in that row in the matrix do have the same expression, and it works for the columns that have values.  But it doesnt set the background to the cells in the columns that don't have a value.  For example above, for John, his name, FEB cell, and MAY cell are colored, but the other months are white.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Yes I'm clicking on the row header which highlights the entire row.  When I set it there, it applies it to each textbox in that row.  When I click on each textbox in that row, they all have the same expression in the background color property

Comment: You may need to create a hidden column with the department field.  That way you can refer to the textbox directly `=Switch(ReportItems!DeptTextBox.Value =  "Accounting", "Yellow"...`

Comment: On the value text box for JAN, FEB etc, try to use an expression to set the value:  =iif(isNothing(YourValueField),"",YourValueField)

Comment: @PeterHe thanks for the response.  I'm not sure how I could do this since that text box is part of a matrix, so it's dynamic based on the number of Employee names, and dates as columns.  Currently it's just the [sum(Fields!QTY.Value)],... so are you suggesting to try something like: 
=IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!QTY.Value))=1,"",Sum(Fields!QTY.Value)) ?  I just gave that a try but same result, only coloring the background color of the cells with values unfortunately

Comment: @Steve-o169 thanks again, can you help me better understand how to create a hidden column with the dept field? I've also edited the original question, the fields showing are the employee_name and dates, but I want to color those employee name rows based on their [department] (a field I have in the dataset, just not displaying) if that makes sense.  I appreciate any and all feedback!

Comment: Basically, I would add a new column after your month/date column, outside of any grouping on the columns.  You can right click the column header and navigate to "Column Visibility" and just select the Hide option.  From there, enter the Department field into the textbox aligned with each name and date and it should work.  I'm guessing the default textbox name will be something like `Textbox6` so just reference it like I did in my other comment with `ReportItems!`.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Genius!!  This worked like a charm!  Thanks so much for helping me through this!  If you want to reply with this as an answer I can mark it as the answer to get you credit if you'd like

Comment: Done, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, my solution was to create a hidden column using the department field and then referring directly to the textbox.  You would add a new column after your month/date column, outside of any grouping on the columns. You can right click the column header and navigate to "Column Visibility" and just select the Hide option. From there, enter the Department field into the textbox aligned with each name and date. I'm guessing the default textbox name will be something like Textbox6 so just reference it with `ReportItems!Textbox6.Value`.  The expression should look like the following.

```
=Switch(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value="Accounting", "Yellow",
        ReportItems!Textbox6.Value="HR", "Blue",
        ReportItems!Textbox6.Value="Marketing", "Red")
```

Comment: Thanks again @steve-o169 !!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to having no data for that month and therefore, no department.

I think you can workaround this by using the MAX of the row's grouping for Department. The MAX will ignore the NULL values and use

```
=Switch(MAX(Fields!Department.Value, "<DeptGroupName>") = "Accounting", "Yellow", 
    MAX(Fields!Department.Value, "<DeptGroupName>") = "HR", "Blue",
    MAX(Fields!Department.Value, "<DeptGroupName>") = "Marketing", "Red")
```

The `<DeptGroupName>` is the name of your row group for departments. This will restrict the values to the ones in that row group.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response!  I may have messed up my original question a little (I went back and updated the original question).  I included that what is being displayed is another field (Employee name), not the department.  I'm looking to set the color based on the department if that makes sense.  When I tried what was suggested above, I got an error for the textboxes in the row saying:

Comment: The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘EMP_NAME1’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset. (rsInvalidAggregateScope)

Comment: The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘EMP_NAME1’ uses an aggregate expression with an invalid recursive/simple flag. The valid values for this flag are ‘Recursive’ and ‘Simple’. (rsInvalidAggregateRecursiveFlag)

Comment: Have you changed the DeptGroupName to the name of your row group of the table? Not the dataset name or the chart name - right click on your row group and click Properties and you want the NAME on the General tab.

Comment: I was actually able to get the answer from someone above.  Maybe I should post the answer I was waiting to see if he wanted to then I could give him the credit for helping me.  thanks